# Get file contents and change a line then save it using PHP

Tags: php

What I am currently doing seems like it is trying to work, however, it doesn't save properly.

I am trying to get the contents of a file, rewrite a line based on user input field (this is just a dummy page for testing) and then save the new file. However, it doesn't replace the contents.

```
$newtext = $_POST['info'];
$txt = 'text.txt';
$h1 = `\<h1 `
$read_txt = file_get_contents($txt);
$add_new = $h1 . $newtext;
$new = preg_replace("'/".$h1."/'", $add_new, $read_txt);
file_put_contents($txt, $new);
```

So what this should do is replace the text `<h1` in the text.txt with `<h1 class="added"`. As I said earlier, this is just a test for replacing (I am putting the `class="added"` in the form). However, it doesn't do this, and I am unsure as to why.

Comment: Where's the problem here - with the `preg_replace()` or saving/writing the file?

Comment: your regex pattern looks incorrect. are you using `/` as the pattern delimiter, or `'`?

Comment: backticks on `$h1` are probably not what you wanted

Comment: Why do you have backticks around `\<h1`? That will try to execute as a shell command. You probably want single quotes. If you turn on error reporting or check your error logs that would have been obvious

Comment: I had to to do `\<` to prevent an error with "<" being there. And as a side note, <h1 wouldn't be a potential thing. It's just an example I could use to make sure characters such as < and > would be fine, should they be in one of the strings included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple string replacement you may just use `str_replace`

http://php.net/manual/it/function.str-replace.php

instaead of `preg_replace` (that in your code is not working because -I'm pretty sure- the regex is malformed).

```
$new = str_replace( '<h1', '<h1 class="added"', $read_txt );
```

Comment: Not possible. It would work in the test given, however, what I am actually trying to get it to do would require a variable, as it will be multiple fields put together.

Comment: I used string constants for simplicity. Of course you can use variables as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Put corrections to your regex pattern as shown below:
`$1` *is numbered reference to the first captured subpattern*

```
...
$add_new = $newtext;
$new = preg_replace("/(\<h1)/", "$1".$add_new, $read_txt);
...
```